# Imprimir resultado si todos las filas coinciden PHP MysQl

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo un problema, soy principante PHP, tengo una tabla donde guardo los items que contiene un pedido.

Cada item se marca como SI, si ya salio a reparto, y se vuelve a marcar como SI si ya fue entregado, puesto que esto puede suceder otro día.

Lo que necesito es saber como hacer la consulta y como imprimir un boton por ejemplo, si todos los items son = SI y SI entonces un boton que diga CERRAR LA VENTA, puesto que todos fueron a reparto y entregados.

oder_product

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+------+
| id | item_id | reparto | entregado |
======================================
| 1  |    1    |   SI    |    NO    |  
======================================

======================================
| 2  |    2    |   SI    |   SI    | 
======================================
| 3  |    2    |   SI    |   SI    | 
======================================
| 4  |    2    |   SI    |   SI    | 
======================================
| 5  |    2    |   SI    |   SI    | 
======================================

======================================
| 6  |    3    |   SI    |    NO    | 
======================================
| 7  |    3    |   SI    |    SI    | 
======================================
```

y bueno estoy trabado desde aquí, puedo seleccionar todos, pero como sabe PHP que son todos realmente?

```
SELECT * FROM oder_product WHERE reparto="SI" AND entregado="SI" AND item_id="2";
```

PHP
Creo que sería algo así:

```
If result=all rows match;
Echo' Todos coinciden AQUI BOTON CERRAR VENTA';

else
Echo' No todos coinciden, faltan $result2 para coincidir;
```

Espero haberme explicado bien, ocupo ayuda en sintaxis MySql si es que usa un tipo de COUNT y en PHP.

Answer (score 2):

Siempre es bueno evitar consultas anidadas, por lo que recomendaría algo como:

```
select IF(SUM(IF(reparto = 'SI' AND entregado = 'SI', 1, 0) = COUNT(*), TRUE, FALSE) as cerrada from order_producto GROUP BY item_id;
```

y luego solo comprarar sobre el campo `cerrada`

Answer (score 0):

Una opción que se me ocurre seria hacer dos consultas contando los registros resultantes, una con la condición  ejemplo:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM oder_product WHERE reparto="SI" AND entregado="SI"
```

y otra sin condición

```
SELECT count(*) FROM oder_product;
```

y si coinciden muestras el botón.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías hacer dos consultas como sugiere Toni en su respuesta, o poner las dos como subconsultas dentro de la misma query:

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM oder_product WHERE item_id = '1') AS num_item,
       (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM oder_product WHERE item_id = '1' AND reparto = 'SI' AND entregado = 'SI') AS num_sies
```

Si el valor de `num_item` y `num_sies` coincide, entonces todas las casillas eran "SI" y el botón para cerrar ventana debe mostrarse.

---

O también podrías simplificar si enfocas elenfocar el problema desde otra manera diferente: se debe **mostrar el botón si ninguna de las filas del producto tiene "NO" en reparto o entrega**. Esa es una consulta mucho más sencilla:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM oder_product WHERE item_id="2" AND (reparto="NO" OR entregado="NO");
```

Si el resultado del `COUNT(*)` es mayor que cero, eso quiere decir que alguna de las filas tiene un "NO" y no se debería mostrar el botón de cerrar ventana. (NOTA: Esto sería teniendo en cuenta que el `item_id` es válido y existe en la tabla, si no existe, el resultado siempre será 0).

Comment: Puedes ver las consultas en estos SQLFiddles: [opción subconsultas](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/57301/13) u [opción contar 'NO's](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/57301/14)